# Always have to create the libs dir after importing MyProject.zip

Tags: flex4.5, flash-builder4.5

Whenever I import a project into Adobe Flash Builder 4.5 on Windows XP / SP3, I get the error:

```
unable to open 'C:\Documents and Settings\afarber\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\MyProject\libs'   MyProject       Unknown Flex Problem
```

Does anybody know a better fix, than navigating into that dir and creating an empty **libs** subdir manually?

What is **libs** used for, maybe I could put some dummy file there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Libs folder is just to hold external libraries that your project uses. You should be able to right click your project and create a new folder named "libs" rather than navigating to the path in the file system and creating it that way.